# Section heading displays text oddly

Tags: mediawiki

I have a wiki page with a normal level 2 section heading.

== 59N ==

But, it displays the N as raised.  Why is it doing that and can I change so the N is inline with other characters?

[image]

Mediawiki 1.35.6, PHP 8.1.2.

Comment: What skin?.....

Comment: @AlexanderMashin I have MonoBook, Timeless, and Vector enabled and have Vector as default. I tested and the 59N lines up fine in MonoBook and Timeless. It just displays the N weird on Vector.